# How should the UI be coded for iPhone and iPad in mind?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am wondering how I should go about designing my App's UI so that it can work with iPhone or iPad without having to recode the App.

My App does not use storyboard and it is pretty simple. So I was thinking of having a Proportions class that would return the size of a button, etc for a given device and then I will dynamically lay things out (Like I would a Java Application).

Is this a good way to do it or am I reinventing the wheel to some extent?

I know from this question [iPhone SDK: How to account for UI layout differences, iPhone vs iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187870/iphone-sdk-how-to-account-for-ui-layout-differences-iphone-vs-ipad) how to deal with it with 2 separate delegates, but what if I programmatically create all the UI?

Thanks

Comment: Don't the user experience is totally different on the iPad, just blowing up the interface might not work. Just look at the mail app, it use the same view on both device, but on the iPad the experience is totally different. You can reuse your views but use then in a different way.

Comment: just curiosity why not storyboards ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can very easily determine what device you are using in the code. Just check it by:

```
 // ipad
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { 
      // do whatever you'd want in iPad
 }

 //iphone
 else {
      // do whatever you'd want in iPhone
 }
```

You can then just create the layout for the iPhone, or the iPad using the above. It seems a bit easier to do this, but you should be more aware with the iPad because it is a much greater screen size. So for the iPad, make sure to add more "flare" into the UI.

Hope this helps!